# Creating the logic for a program that reverses an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, logic

I'm having a little trouble with homework. I believe I have a solution to the problem, but I'd like to make sure. Here's the question.

"Create the logic for a program that prompts a user for ten numbers and stores them in an array. Pass the array to a method that reverses the order of the numbers. Display the reversed numbers in the main program."

Here's what I have so far:

```
Start
         Declarations
         NUM numbers[10]

    for count = 0 to 9 step 1
         input numbers[x]
    endfor 
    reverseArray(numbers[x])
    for count = 0 to 9 step 1
         output nums[x]
    endfor
Stop

reverseArray(NUM nums[x])
      Declarations
      NUM nums[10]
 for count = 0 to 9 step 1
      if nums[x] > nums[x + 1]
           Swap()
      endif
      nums[x] = nums[x + 1]
 endfor
return nums[x]
```

Any help would be appreciated. This isn't in any specific program, so the syntax doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Mind giving a possible income-outcome example?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Any basic language that a complete beginner would understand is fine. This is a Programming & Logic course, so we're not working with any specific language. Just working with the structure of programs